# Error in summary.rms(sfit) : adjustment values not defined here or with datadist for some variables

Tags: r

I estimated a regression model in R namely r.

And I want to get summary of r. Fo this, I used the code >summary(r)

But, I get the following error message

> > Error in summary.rms(r) : 
> >     adjustment values not defined here or with datadist for age sex

How to correct that error?

Comment: I found the following link https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rms/versions/5.0-1/topics/datadist, but it is still very unclear why datadist is necessary and what it does

Answer (score 11):

You should add this two lines before trying `summary(r)`:

```
dd <- datadist(x)
options(datadist="dd")
```

Where `x` is your dataset.

Comment: This works for me. My question is why is this necessary?

Comment: datadist evaluates the dataset and summary(r) utilizes this to present the summary. For example, a cox regression on a continuous variable with the rms package adjusts the estimates in the summary for scale. This scale adjustment is based on the 25 and 75 percentiles determined in datadist.